# Basic Input from the Command Line in Rebol

Tags: user-input, rebol

I am currently in the process of learning Rebol.

In other languages I know, I can read input from the command line, for example in Java:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
sc.nextLine();
```

In C#

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

In C

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

I was wondering how one would accomplish the same thing in Rebol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `input` command to ask for input at the console.

```
>> name: input
Joe
== "Joe"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ask` function complements `input` by printing a string prior to requesting input:

```
age: ask "How old are you? "
```

It also has a `/hide` refinement to conceal input:

```
pass: ask/hide "Enter your password: "
```

*At this time, /hide is [not implemented](http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=1400) in Rebol 3 alphas*

A longer answer (and for intermediate-level at least) would include monitoring the `system/ports/input` port (you can do `source input` for how this is done for you)—this can be used in cases where input doesn't originate at the console (such as shell, CGI).

Comment: sourcing input will also allow you to figure out how to manage single key presses, (useful for text menus, which don't force you to press enter... do people still know what a text menu is? ;-).